# Selecting with Cases

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns, case

Please Consider :

```
Subsets[Flatten[ParallelTable[{i, j}, {i, 1, 96}, {j, 1, 4}], 1], {4}]
```

I need to select all the Sublist such that the the i value is never the same within each sublist of 4

{{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1}} should be accepted while {{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{6,1}} should be rejected. The Value 1 for i being repeated 2 times.

I know I could do this with Cases, but don`t understand the Syntax of it, and find the help on Cases rather empty compared to its potential applications.

Comment: your table is { {{a,b},{c,d}} ....} and not {{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{gh}}, ...

Comment: @belisarius, actually it would not let me do Tuples[...,4] :-( What would you suggest :-) ?

Comment: :D ... I was waiting for your question ... :D

Comment: ahaha, Subsets works but seems to want to eat my machine !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4514/discussion-between-500-and-belisarius)

Comment: If you actually want to produce the set of results given in the example, I suggest that you do not create the quads with duplicate elements in the first place.

Comment: @Mr Wizard, Shall I ask a separate question ?

Comment: @Mr. Those are still `96 95 94 93 4^4 = 20.410.122.240` elements

Comment: @belisarius are there not `Binomial[96*4, 4]` = 891,881,376 elements in the example `Subsets`, before filtering?  (Still, I am not saying the full set will be possible.)

Comment: @Mr. My reasoning goes like this: You have 96 choices for the first element(a) of the first {a,b}, 95 for the first element of the second {a,b}, etc. Then, for the second element (b), you can chose it freely from Range[4] four times (one for each {a,b})

Comment: @belisarius wouldn't that be permutations of subsets?  Anyway, it doesn't appear to correlate to real results.  Would not your logic suggest that for `Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 12}, {j, 1, 4}]~Flatten~1~Subsets~{4}` there are 12*11*10*9*4^4 = 3,041,280 filtered possibilities, yet actual evaluation yields 126,720?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the variable `data`, the following should do it:

```
Select[data, Length@Union[#[[All, 1]]] === 4 &]
```

This takes the "`i`"-value (i.e. first element), and checks that the 4 values are all different (i.e. if we remove the duplicates we still have 4 of them)

Answer (score 3):

This response assumes that the input data is a list of tuples of four pairs each, e.g.:

```
$data = {{{3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}} , {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {6, 1}}};
```

Using `Cases`, one could name and compare the first elements of each pair to ensure that they are unequal:

```
Cases[
  $data
, {{a_, _}, {b_, _}, {c_, _}, {d_, _}} /; Unequal[a, b, c, d]
]
```

Another use of `Cases` compares the first elements of each pair without naming them:

```
Cases[
  $data
, tuple_ /; Unequal @@ tuple[[All, 1]]
]
```

Alternatively, one could use `DeleteCases` and exclude tuples with at least two pairs with the same initial value:

```
DeleteCases[
  $data
, {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___}
]
```

One might think that this last expression could be:

```
(* warning: does not work *)
Cases[$data, Except[{___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___}]]
```

... but `Except` does not permit named patterns in the first argument.

Comment: Thank You very much. I think this should be on the Cases help file in MMA !

Answer (score 2):

WReach already covered `Cases` well, so here is another approach.

```
Pick[data, Signature /@ data[[All, All, 1]], 1 | -1]
```

It is faster than most of the other methods, but still not as fast as the fixed-length `Cases` method.

Comment: @Mr, I am struggling to formulate my question for the generation part. How would you name the process I am trying to build ? Do you think there is away to aggregate the 2 questions ? Maybe generate under Constraints ? I am sorry, but really on the edge of my understanding here ! Thank You for your attention !

Comment: @500 I greatly overestimated the memory saving you could get, so it may not be worth bothering.  Nevertheless a good implementation may be faster than the create-and-filter approach.  If you choose to post the question, I doubt I could name it better than you.  Certainly the title can be edited later if it is found to be confusing.