# Efficient And Conditional Tuples or Subsets

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, set, tuples, subset

Stepping back from the following question :

[Selecting with Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892994/selecting-with-cases)

I need to generate a random Set (1 000 000 items would be enough)

```
Subsets[Flatten[ParallelTable[{i, j}, {i, 1, 96}, {j, 1, 4}], 1], {4}]
```

Further, I need to reject any quadruples with non-unique first elements, such as `{{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{6,1}}`.

But the above is impossible on a laptop. How could I just draw uniformly one millions sets avoiding killing my machine ?

Comment: Can yo clarify the question?  Do you need to get a random sample of size 1 000 000 from the list generated by `Subsets[Flatten[ParallelTable[{i, j}, {i, 1, 96}, {j, 1, 4}], 1], {4}]` ?  (Which is in fact too long to generate in practice, with 891 881 376 elements)

Comment: Yes that is it ! THank You for your attention, feel free to Edit the question or advise me on what I should write.

Comment: 500, it is not clear in your question that you want to reject any quads with first-element duplication, such as `{{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{6,1}}`.

Comment: @Mr. Please Edit or i`ll have to quote :-) "any quads with first-element duplication, such as {{1,1},{1,2},{2,3},{6,1}}" This is exactly it. But the example shows that in the Selecting with Cases ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you have a base set you need to generate 4-element subsets of,

```
baseSet = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 96}, {j, 1, 4}], 1];
```

you can use `RandomSample` as follows:

```
RandomSample[baseSet, 4]
```

This gives you a length-4 random subset of `baseSet`.  Generating a million of them takes 2.5 seconds on my very old machine:

```
Timing[subsets = Table[RandomSample[baseSet, 4], {1000000}];]
```

Not all of what we get are going to be different subsets, so we need to remove duplicates using `Union`:

```
subsets = Union[subsets];
```

After this I'm still left with 999 971 items in a sample run, thanks to the much larger number of possible subsets (`Binomial[Length[baseSet], 4] == 891 881 376`)

Comment: I believe it is worth noting that: `baseSet = Tuples@Range@{96, 4}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't know `Range` could take a list!

Comment: I forgot that myself for a moment when I posted, which is why there is the edit symbol next to my comment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This should also do the trick, and it runs faster than Szabolcs' proposal.

```
(t=Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 96}], RandomInteger[{1, 4}]}, {10^6}, {4}]); //Timing
```

I saw no need to remove duplicate subsets since we're sampling, not trying to produce the entire population.  (But you can easily remove duplicates if you so wish.)

BTW, for this case, `Table` runs faster than `ParallelTable`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks for the edits. I used dummy iterators without realizing they were not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a slight variation of David's method will produce the duplicate-free form requested in the original post.

```
set = 
  With[{r = Range@96},
    {RandomSample[r, 4], RandomInteger[{1, 4}, 4]}\[Transpose] ~Table~ {1*^6}
  ];
```

This of course does not produce 10^6 unique samples, but Szabolcs showed how that may be done, and the cost is not great.